# Java script returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using String operations on javascript, I'm novice in JS. Here is my code.

```
function updateCLOB(row) {
  var attrStr = row.get('CLOB_DATA');

  if (attrStr == null && attrStr == undefined) {
    return row;
  } else {
    var res = attrStr.split('||');

    for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
print('RES'=res[i]);
      var temp = res[i].split('/');
      var column = temp[4];
      var value = temp[12];
      row.put('WORKODR_' + column, value);
      print('WORKODR_' + column + ' is ' + value);
    }
  }
  return row;
}
```

My Clob data would be like 212323/2/January/3/4/5/6/7/1/2/3/4/5sd/123/45/56||............

Now im getting "undefined" in the output.

WORKODR_undefined is undefined.

Please let me know what im missing.

I tried to print the "res" value by and its printing as

```
RES2
RES1
RES2
.
.
.
```

Its splitting on every character. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure that `attrStr` is a string with value `212323/2/January/3/4/5/6/7/1/2/3/4/5sd/123/45/56||212323/2/January/3/4/5/6/7/1/2/3/4/5sd/123/45/56....`. I tried it in a fiddle and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/z78p7d5L/9/

Comment: How can something be null and undefined at the same time?

Comment: And what do you see with `console.log(res[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if(attrStr==null && attrStr==undefined){
```

Should be:

```
if(attrStr!=null && attrStr!=undefined){
```

I am assuming you want to make sure it is not null and not undefined the if condition you have could never be met it can't be null and undefined...

Comment: Actually i'm returning the input as is if its null, the print statement is printing the results.

Comment: Then you should do: `if(attrStr==null || attrStr==undefined){`

Comment: No need to check for both: `foo == null` will catch both `null` and `undefined`. `if (foo === null)` will be false for `undefined`.

Comment: or used the falsy value would be valid too, if(!sttrStr)

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
if(attrStr!=null && typeof(attrStr)!='undefined'){
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (attrStr == null && attrStr == undefined) {
```

try using

```
if (!attrStr) {
```

the condition will be valid for null, undefined and zero length strings.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, the issue lies in the ||. Since I called this JS from a java app, I think the escaping of pipe is mandotary.

I used
    var res = attrStr.split('\|\|'); and voila it worked !